# MySQL: Is it possible to create a query that evaluates data from different records?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I've got a table like this.
It shows the starttime and endtime of different restaurants on different weekdays.

| No | Restaurant | Weekday | Starttime | Endtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Mon | 10:00 | 21:00 |
| 2 | A | Tue | 10:00 | 21:00 |
| 3 | A | Wed | 19:00 | 08:00 |
| 4 | A | Thu |  |  |
| 5 | A | Fri | 10:00 | 21:00 |
| 6 | A | Sat | 10:00 | 21:00 |
| 7 | A | Sun | 19:00 | 08:00 |
| 8 | B | Mon | 11:00 | 21:00 |
| 9 | B | Tue | 11:00 | 21:00 |
| 10 | B | Wed | 11:00 | 23:00 |
| 11 | B | Thu | 11:00 | 23:00 |
| 12 | B | Fri | 11:00 | 16:00 |
| 13 | B | Sat | 10:00 | 00:00 |
| 14 | B | Sun | 00:00 | 13:00 |

What I want is this.
Given the current time, the code should display which restaurant is currently open.
This is what I tried.

```
(CASE WHEN user_time.start_time > user_time.end_time AND ( CURTIME() < user_time.end_time OR CURTIME() > user_time.start_time ) THEN 1
      WHEN user_time.start_time < user_time.end_time AND ( CURTIME() > user_time.start_time AND CURTIME() < user_time.end_time ) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
 END) = 0 AND user_time.weekday = WEEKDAY(CURDATE())
```

It finds the current weekday and the corresponding opentime and endtime to compare with the current time.
But the problem occurs when a restaurant starts in the evening and ends the next day.

1. In case of No 4, restaurant A is closed but actually it is open until 8:00.
   If the current time is 7:00, restaurant A should appear open.
2. When we look at No 1 and No 7, the previous day of Monday is Sunday.
   So if the current time is Monday 7:00AM, the query should compare the time with
   Sunday's open time and give the result "open".
3. Also I would like to have a query that does the opposite, that finds the
   restaurants that are currently closed.

This means the query should be able to decide which time data to use, today's or yesterday's.
Please help me find a solution.

MySQL server version is 10.4.17 MariaDB.

The datatype of No is int, everything else is VARCHAR.

Comment: can you pls post the datatype of each field and the Version of your MySQL Server

Comment: *But the problem occurs when a restaurant starts in the evening and ends the next day.* Convert time value to numeric and add `240000` to `Endtime` when `Starttime+0 > Endtime+0`.

Comment: Thank you, Akina. That was helpful. But let's suppose it is Thursday morning 7AM. According to the table, restaurant A would be still open, but adding 24hours to the endtime of Thursday wouldn't help finding this.

Comment: @CharlieSchwab - can please post the dreate of the table to see the datatypes. i have seen that also wrong times in the table. 24:00 is incorrect. 23:59:59 or 00:00:00 is only valid. i know that this is not the main problem

Comment: I suspect you're using MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have build a Table with 2 new virtual fields. This fields are automatic filled. I use a little trick for the weekday. So 1 generate a date and the weekday is the the day of month. It only use for compare.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_time
WHERE
    TIMESTAMP(CONCAT('2000-01-0',DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()),' ',current_time()))
    BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
OR
    IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) <> 'SUNDAY' , FALSE,
    TIMESTAMP(CONCAT('2000-01-0',DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+7,' ',current_time()))
    BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
    );
```

**the table**

```
CREATE TABLE `user_time` (
  `No` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Restaurant` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Weekday` enum('SUNDAY','MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY') DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_start` timestamp GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(concat('2000-01-0',`Weekday` + 0,' ',`start_time`) as datetime)) STORED,
  `date_end` timestamp GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(concat('2000-01-0',`Weekday` + 0,' ',`end_time`) + interval if(cast(`start_time` as time) >= cast(`end_time` as time),1,0) day as datetime)) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`No`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**insert some data**

```
INSERT INTO `user_time` (`No`, `Restaurant`, `Weekday`, `start_time`, `end_time`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 'MONDAY', '12:00', '13:00'),
    (2, 'a', 'MONDAY', '14:00', '02:00'),
    (3, 'b', 'MONDAY', '16:00', '18:00'),
    (4, 'c', 'TUESDAY','21:00', '18:00');
```

**see whats generated**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM user_time;
+----+------------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| No | Restaurant | Weekday | start_time | end_time | date_start          | date_end            |
+----+------------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | a          | MONDAY  | 12:00      | 13:00    | 2000-01-02 12:00:00 | 2000-01-02 13:00:00 |
|  2 | a          | MONDAY  | 14:00      | 02:00    | 2000-01-02 14:00:00 | 2000-01-03 02:00:00 |
|  3 | b          | MONDAY  | 16:00      | 18:00    | 2000-01-02 16:00:00 | 2000-01-02 18:00:00 |
|  4 | c          | TUESDAY | 21:00      | 18:00    | 2000-01-03 21:00:00 | 2000-01-04 18:00:00 |
+----+------------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

**query current date**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * 
    -> FROM user_time
    -> WHERE
    -> TIMESTAMP(CONCAT('2000-01-0',DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()),' ',current_time()))
    -> BETWEEN date_start AND date_end;
+----+------------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| No | Restaurant | Weekday | start_time | end_time | date_start          | date_end            |
+----+------------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  4 | c          | TUESDAY | 21:00      | 18:00    | 2000-01-03 21:00:00 | 2000-01-04 18:00:00 |
+----+------------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: Thank you for your deep investigation into my problem. I believe it will solve the first problem. But what about the second problem? What if Restaurant "a" starts 9:00PM, Sunday and ends 11:00AM Monday? If the current time is 10:00AM Monday, restaurant "a" should appear open.

Comment: This works also. see Row No 4. it opens at TUESDAY 2100 and close WEDNESDAY 18:00. Today is WEDNESDAY and it was selected in my query

Comment: I mean Sunday is 2000-01-07, right? And Monday is 2000-01-01. So how can query select between Sunday and the next Monday?

Comment: i have change the first query, but not testet

Answer (score 1):

You can split to 2 rows each row that contains `Endtime` of the next day:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, Weekday day, Starttime time1, Endtime time2 FROM user_time
  WHERE Starttime < Endtime 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, Weekday, Starttime, '23:59' FROM user_time
  WHERE Starttime > Endtime 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, 
         DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(LEFT(CURRENT_DATE, 8), Weekday), '%X-%V-%W') + INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%a'), 
         '00:00', Endtime 
  FROM user_time
  WHERE Starttime > Endtime
)  
SELECT No, Restaurant, Weekday, Starttime, Endtime 
FROM cte
WHERE day = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%a')
  AND NOW() BETWEEN CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE, ' ', time1, ':00') AND CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE, ' ', time2, ':00')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=7b138ed0899b7493b6014ec8d0c00311).

Comment: its not working - **WHERE weekday = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%a')** will generate the Day of the current date and if it later 00:00 in the column Weekday was the day of yesterday

Comment: @ forpas - i have modifyed your isnsert so that row NO 9 also must be selected. The Problem is when the start day is yesterday an the start time yesterday is greater the start time of today. see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=5807efa959a2890e82e30543531b7aa2

Comment: @BerndBuffen this is why in this case: Starttime > Endtime, I split the row in 2 rows, so if the row is ('9', 'B', 'Tue', '22:00', '21:00') it is divided into ('9', 'B', 'Tue', '22:00', '23:59') and ('9', 'B', 'Wed', '00:00', '21:00').

Comment: oh, oh, oh, my mistake !!! you are 100% correct. SORRY.. I'm sure I'm already in Christmas fashion. - vote up